# CodeIgniter MySQL query where not working after a label

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to get result from database conditionally.
like where a = 1 and b != 2 and so much conditions...

here is my code sample

```
$u = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;

$hide=$this->find_hide_post();

$friend=$this->get_all_contacts();
```

after this i start my main query

```
$this->db->where('user_id',$u);

foreach($friend as $fr)
{
  foreach($fr as $f)
  {
    if($f->sub_id !=$u)
    {
      $this->db->or_where('user_id', $f->sub_id);
    }
    elseif($f->obj_id !=$u)
    {
      $this->db->or_where('user_id', $f->obj_id);
    }

    $this->db->where('time >', $f->time);
  }
}
```

i get good correct result, but whenever i add these lines i didnt get correct result. but i need to remove those posts from result.

```
foreach($hide as $h)
{
  $this->db->where('id !=', $h->post_id);
}
```

lastly i get through this way

```
$result=$this->db->get('my_wall');
$row=$result->result();
print_r($row);
```

the result is:

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [user_id] => 19
            [post] => 
            [img] => public/users/wall/pic/Messenger14.png
            [doc] => 
            [video] => 
            [link] => 
            [link_name] => 
            [access_id] => 
            [like] => 0
            [time] => 1340792296
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 19
        [user_id] => 19
        [post] => This is my test Documents
        [img] => 
        [doc] => public/users/wall/doc/19/20745322_temp.pdf
        [video] => 
        [link] => 
        [link_name] => 
        [access_id] => 
        [like] => 0
        [time] => 1340792743
    )
```

and i want to avoid those post where id is not 19 or like something. but my last query is not working :(, result is same.

Comment: What is your issue? What's not your "correct" result?

Comment: can you post the resulting sql statement?

Comment: hello @randy! i paste result. please give your suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

It's because your logic is not mixing well with CodeIgniter's Active Record class. You cannot mix `or_where` and `where` or else you'll get fuzzy logic. You'll need to fix your logic in order for your query to be proper. Here's what I suggest.

Rewrite your `foreach` statements to pack everything into an array.

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($friend as $fr) {
    foreach($fr as $f) {
        if (...) {
            $ids[] = $f->sub_id;
        }
    }
    $this->db->where('time >', $f->time);
}
```

... And so on. When you're finished with your `foreach` statement, add the following line instead.

```
$this->db->where_in('user_id', $ids);
```

This should give you the ability to properly render your SQL statement with:

```
foreach($hide as $h)
{
  $this->db->where('id !=', $h->post_id);
}
```